# How to update multiple time a discord.js's interaction using setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discordjs v13.6 bot in typescript who post an embed object with the date of day when using `/day` interaction command.
In a nutshell: I make `/day` and an embed is posted by my bot with the current date, weather, etc...

It's work fine and I added 3 buttons under the embed:

1. "reload" button: it will simply update the embed (with current weather forecast).
2. "previous" button: to update embed's interaction to the previous day.
3. "next" button: to update embed's interaction to the next day.

My code work as it should like this for the 3 buttons attached to my embed:

```js
import { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } from 'discord.js';

// All customId property are formated like: `{method}@{date}`, ie: `reload@2022-03-10` is the button who'll reload the embed to date 03/10/2022.
export const createNavigationButtons = (date) => (
  new MessageActionRow().addComponents([
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`prev@${date}`)
      .setStyle('SECONDARY')
      .setEmoji("946186554517389332"),
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`reload@${date}`)
      .setStyle('SUCCESS')
      .setEmoji("946190012154794055"),
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`next@${date}`)
      .setStyle('SECONDARY')
      .setEmoji("946186699745161296")
  ])
)
```

For the logic:

```js
import { ButtonInteraction               } from 'discord.js';
import { createEmbed                     } from "../utils/embed";
import { createNavigationButtons         } from "../utils/buttons";
import * as year                           from "../../resources/year.json";
import * as moment                         from 'moment';
import { setTimeout as wait }  from 'node:timers/promises';

// This function is called in the on('interactionCreate') event, when interaction.isButton() is true
export const button = async (interaction: ButtonInteraction): Promise<void> => {
  const [action, date]: string[] = interaction.customId?.split('@');
  await interaction.deferUpdate();
  await wait(1000);
  const newDate: string = {
    prev:   moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").subtract(1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    next:   moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(     1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    reload: date
  }[action];
  await interaction.editReply({
    embeds:     [await createEmbed(year[newDate])],
    components: [createNavigationButtons(newDate)]
  });
}
```

It works just as I wished. BUT, everybody can use theses buttons (and I don't want to send `/day`'s answer as ephemeral, I want everybody to see the response). So, if we use `/day 2022-03-10` the embed for March 10, 2022. but if the **author** or **someone else** (I don't mind) use the button, the embed will be updated with another date (and that's fine by me !). But I want to roll back my embed to the original date few seconds / minutes after the button is pressed.

I tried somes primitive way like the `setTimeout` like this:

```js
export const button = async (interaction: ButtonInteraction, config: any): Promise<void> => {
  // In this test, button's customId are formated like {method}@{date}@{date's origin} (where 'origin' is the original requested's date, optional)
  const [action, date, origin]: string[] = interaction.customId?.split('@');
  await interaction.deferUpdate();
  await wait(1000);
  const newDate: string = {
    prev:   moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").subtract(1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    next:   moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(     1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    reload: date
  }[action];
  // Here is my setTimeout who is supposed to recursively recall this function with a "reload" and the original date
  setTimeout(async () => {
    interaction.customId = `reload@${origin ?? date}`;
    console.log(interaction.customId);
    await button(interaction, config);
  }, 5000);
  await interaction.editReply({
    embeds:     [await createEmbed(year[newDate])],
    components: [createNavigationButtons(newDate)]
  });
};
```

When I press my buttons with this, it's correctly updated but 5sec (`setTimeout`'s value) after it end up with an error saying:

```
reload@2022-03-10
/home/toto/tata/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:180
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                             ^
Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (/home/toto/tata/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:180:46)
    at button (/home/toto/tata/src/services/button.ts:12:21)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/toto/tata/src/services/button.ts:28:21)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}
```

I understand that it seems I can't reupdate my interaction with the same token like that, so how shoul I achieve my goal ? may be the `setTimeout` isn't a propper solution (but it was quite simple to implemant so I tried it first). Any Ideas ?

Comment: As the error indicates, the primary issue is `deferUpdate()`. The first time you use `button()`, it has already deferred the update. Then when you recursively call `button()`, it tries to defer the update again, realizes the update is already deferred, and throws that error. You simply need to prevent the `deferUpdate()` line from being used on recursive calls. Maybe add an extra parameter to the method (e.g. `defer`), and set it to true only when calling `button()` recursively. Or add an `if (!interaction.deferred)` before the `deferUpdate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully reached my objective like this:

```js
// All customId property are formated like: `{method}@{date}@{origin}`, ie: `reload@2022-03-10` is the button who'll reload the embed to date 03/10/2022.
export const createNavigationButtons = (date: string, mode?: boolean) => (
  new MessageActionRow().addComponents([
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`prev@${date}${!mode ? `@${date}` : ''}`)
      .setStyle('SECONDARY')
      .setEmoji("946186554517389332"),
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`reload@${date}`)
      .setStyle('SUCCESS')
      .setEmoji("946190012154794055"),
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`remind@${date}`)
      .setStyle('PRIMARY')
      .setEmoji("946192601806155806"),
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`next@${date}${!mode ? `@${date}` : ''}`)
      .setStyle('SECONDARY')
      .setEmoji("946186699745161296")
  ])
);

export const createButtons = (date, mode?: boolean) => ({
  components: [ createNavigationButtons(date, mode) ]
});
```

```js
export const button = async (interaction: ButtonInteraction, config: any): Promise<void> => {
  const [action, date, origin]: string[] = interaction.customId?.split('@');
  const newDate: string = {
    prev:   moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").subtract(1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    next:   moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(     1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    reload: date
  }[action];
  origin && !interaction.deferred && setTimeout(async () => {
    await interaction.editReply({
      embeds: [await createEmbed(year[origin], config.server)],
      ...createButtons(origin)
    });
  }, 120000);
  !interaction.deferred && await interaction.deferUpdate();
  await interaction.editReply({
    embeds: [await createEmbed(year[newDate], config.server)],
    ...createButtons(newDate, true)
  });
};
```

In a nutshell, when I first create the embed I place a `@{origin}` (who's a date), and when I navigate and update my embed with my buttons, I don't send origin (only `{action}@{date}`, not `{action}@{date}@origin` by passing `true` to my `createButtons` method.